# Как добавить внешнюю ссылку на картинку в img(src="")?

Tags: pug

В документе product-list.pug я добавляю карточки продуктов и при добавлении ссылки на внешнюю картинку по url она не подтягивается:

```
                each product in prods 
                .card 
                    h3 #{product.title}
                    p  
                        img(src='#{product.imageUrl}', alt="#{product.imageUrl}")
                    p #{product.price}
                    p #{product.description}
```

Как сделать, чтобы ссылка на картинку работала? К примеру, ссылка "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.5SUhFpKmTir7RkmDLUqUXgAAAA%26pid%3DApi&f=1"

Answer (score 0):

Всего-то `img(src=product.imageUrl)`